# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'. ... starting run-android failing last 3 days with no solution to it

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 870 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
- daemon started successfully
  info Installing the app...
  Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 1 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> 28 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 23 up-to-date
> Note: D:\working-projects\TestProject\android\app\src\debug\java\com\testproject\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
> java.io.IOException: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: D:\working-projects\TestProject\android\app\src\debug\java\com\testproject\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
> java.io.IOException: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s

```
at makeError (D:\working-projects\TestProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\working-projects\TestProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\working-projects\TestProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\working-projects\TestProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Have been facing this issue all of a sudden
I have reinstalled the whole setup again for react native but still getting this same error. Getting no clues as to what is the exact issue.. All help appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get it working ... the issue was of bad sectors on HDD ... just ran chkdsk /f/r and everything started to work fine after its completion